# Updating a scheduled task with 'repeat every x hours' causes it to be triggered on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

**Synopsis** 
I have a scheduled task that runs a program with highest privileges every 4 hours. On Windows 10 version 1803 (build 17134.81), any update to this task causes it to be triggered as soon as the task is saved. The task is triggered even if the update is to disable the trigger! Disabling the 'run every x hours' clause seems to be the only way to get around this issue. However, saving the same task on Windows 7 (SP1) does not trigger it.

**Details** 
Updating a task logs [event #140](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd363717(v=ws.10)) (task registration updated) in the task history. At the same instant, [event #107](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd348590(v=ws.10)) (task triggered on scheduler) is logged and the task starts up: 
[Link to event history screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2NNF.png)

The 'run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed' option on the Settings tab does not have any effect on this behavior.

Has anyone else come across this issue? Please suggest a reasonable workaround that does not cause the task to be triggered as soon as it is saved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Prevent a Task Scheduler Task from Executing on Setting Updates

Set the **Edit Trigger** to run at an interval of **One Time** and then in ***Advanced settings*** section, select **Repeat task every** `4 hour` with **for a duration of** `indefinitely` but be sure the **Start time** up top is the time which you want this task to first be run.

[image]

> **Note:** A key point here is to be sure the **Start time** is the *exact time* you want the process to run the first time but of a *prior date* and then it'll run first starting only at that *time*.

Furthermore, from the **Settings** tab you might also *uncheck* the **Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed** as this can cause this problem as well.

[image]

Comment: Now I understand your handle Pimp Juice IT........you got the Juice!

Comment: That and Moab Utah! Been there twice and would love to live there if I could afford land. Nice answer, your a BadA** my friend.